# Angular9 - @Input decorator issue

Tags: angular

I have setup the following parent-child component interaction using @Input decorator. But this doesnt seem to work. Can anyone please help me with this?

**Parent ts file :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Covid19Service } from '../services/get-covid19-data';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-countries',
   templateUrl: 'countries.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['countries.component.css']
})

export class CountriesComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private covid19Service: Covid19Service) { }

   countries: Array<string> = [];
   countriesCount: Number;
   selectedCountry: string = 'Sample';


   ngOnInit() {
     this.covid19Service.getCountries().subscribe(data => {
        this.countriesCount = data['affectedCountries'];
        this.countries = data['countries'];
     });
   }

  countrySelected(country: string) {
    this.selectedCountry = country;
    console.log(`Selected Country from Parent: ${this.selectedCountry}`);
    /*         console.log(`Clicked on : ${country}!`);
            this.covid19Service.getCountry(country).subscribe(data => {
                console.log(`${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
            }); */
}
}
```

**Parent HTML:**

```
<div>
<li *ngFor="let country of countries">
    <span class="badge" (click)="countrySelected(country)">{{country}}</span>
</li>
</div>
<app-country [country]="selectedCountry"></app-country>
```

**Child ts file:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-country',
  templateUrl: 'country.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['country.component.css']
})
export class CountryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() country: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(`Selected Country in Child: ${this.country}`);
  }
 }
```

**Child HTMLfile:**

```
<p>Country component works!</p>
<p>This is the selected Country: {{country}}</p>
```

The above code using @Input component doesnt work. Can anyone please help me with this? I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm lost. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you any errors in the console?

Comment: What's the result exactly?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I'm not getting any errors in the console(I'm using firefox)

Comment: @ShamPooSham Only log I'm getting is : "Selected Country from Parent: Trinidad and Tobago"

Comment: @TonyMathew and what's the rendered result? (not in the console)

Comment: @TonyMathew It's working well!! you can [check it online](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rosalind-bwozg?file=/src/app/country/country.component.ts)

Comment: can you state your expected and actual outcomes/

Comment: @bryan - I'm just trying to pass "selectedCountry" variable value from parent component to child component and display it in child component html

Comment: That’s your expected behavior. What’s your actual

Comment: Actual behavior is that "selectedCountry"isn't getting displayed in child component. I have tried printing the variable in child component. Even that didn't work